# Title of HTML report defaults to bottom of report

Tags: html, powershell

I have a script that pulls DHCP statistics, (Ranges, ScopeIDs, Scope Options, ect) and output to an HTML report, when it outputs to the report the title of the report is defaulting to the bottom and I can't figure out where my formatting error is .

```
$Target = '########'
    #$Title= "<p>Test Title</p>"
    $Path = '##################################\'
    $Name = 'Test3.html'
    $TestO = @()
    $ScopeIDs = Get-DhcpServerv4Scope -ComputerName $Target | Select "Name","SubnetMask","StartRange","EndRange","ScopeID","State"
    $ScopeOut = $ScopeIDs | ConvertTo-Html -As Table | Out-String | Out-File -FilePath $Path$Name
    #$Head = "<h2>Error reporting for #########</h2>"
    $Header = @"
    <style>
    TABLE {border-width: 1px: border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-collaspe: collapse;}
    TH {border-width: 1px; padding: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; background-color: #6495ED}
    TD {border-width: 1px; padding: 3px; border-style:  solid; border-color: black;}
    </style>
    "@
    
    ForEach ($ScopeID in $ScopeIDs){ $TestO +=
    $ScopeStat = Get-DhcpServerv4ScopeStatistics -ComputerName $Target -ScopeId $ScopeID.ScopeID | Select "ScopeID", "Free","InUse","PercentageInUse" | ConvertTo-Html -As Table | Out-String | Out-File -FilePath  $Path$Name -Append
    $OptValue = Get-DhcpServerv4OptionValue -ComputerName $Target -ScopeId $ScopeID.ScopeId -All | Select-Object  Name,OptionId,Type,@{Name="Value";Expression={$_.Value}} | ConvertTo-Html -As Table | Out-String | Out-File -FilePath  $Path$Name -Append
    }
    $Body = $ScopeStat + $OptValue
    ConvertTo-Html -PreContent "<h1>Test</h1>" -Head $Header -Body $Body   | Out-File $Path$Name -Append
```

[image]

Comment: Where is the title in the sample screenshot?

Comment: Looks like you are appending on an existing file with the flag -Append. So html gets added to end of the file.

Comment: When that -append at the end is removed the data is not populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to reformat your sample to break the long pipelines down into smaller chunks:

```
foreach( $ScopeID in $ScopeIDs )
{

    $ScopeStat = Get-DhcpServerv4ScopeStatistics -ComputerName $Target -ScopeId $ScopeID.ScopeID `
        | Select "ScopeID", "Free","InUse","PercentageInUse" `
        | ConvertTo-Html -As Table `
        | Out-String `
        | Out-File -FilePath $Path$Name -Append

    $OptValue = Get-DhcpServerv4OptionValue -ComputerName $Target -ScopeId $ScopeID.ScopeId -All `
        | Select-Object Name,OptionId,Type,@{Name="Value";Expression={$_.Value}} `
        | ConvertTo-Html -As Table `
        | Out-String `
        | Out-File -FilePath $Path$Name -Append

}

$Body = $ScopeStat + $OptValue

ConvertTo-Html -PreContent "<h1>Test</h1>" -Head $Header -Body $Body `
    | Out-File $Path$Name -Append
```

To summarise, you're using `Out-File` to append a full `<html>...</html>` document for each result from `Get-DhcpServerv4ScopeStatistics` and `Get-DhcpServerv4OptionValue` onto the end of `$Path$Name` and *then* you're appending the `$Header` as *another* full html document afterwards.

Note that `$Body = $ScopeStat + $OptValue` does nothing because `$ScopeStat` and `$OptValue` are both `$null` - they capture the return value from `Out-File`, but `Out-File` doesn't actually return anything - it writes to a file instead!

What you're probably going to have to do instead is write the html header and footer yourself and then write each table as a `<table>...</table>` fragment (note the `-Fragment` switch on `ConvertTo-Html`):

```
Add-Content -Path $Path$Name -Value "<html>";
Add-Content -Path $Path$Name -Value $Header;
Add-Content -Path $Path$Name -Value "<h1>Test</h1>";

foreach( $ScopeID in $ScopeIDs )
{

    $table = Get-DhcpServerv4ScopeStatistics -ComputerName $Target -ScopeId $ScopeID.ScopeID `
        | Select "ScopeID", "Free","InUse","PercentageInUse" `
        | ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Fragment
    Add-Content -Path $Path$Name -Value $table 

    $table = Get-DhcpServerv4OptionValue -ComputerName $Target -ScopeId $ScopeID.ScopeId -All `
        | Select-Object Name,OptionId,Type,@{Name="Value";Expression={$_.Value}} `
        | ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Fragment
    Add-Content -Path $Path$Name -Value $table 

}

Add-Content -Path $Path$Name "</html>";
```

Comment: That worked like a charm, I just had to change the formatting of the scopeID variable and off the races, thank you!